# Compiliation Errors "Undefined Symbols"

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I tried compiling on my new cocos2d engine, and got these errors:

`Undefined symbols:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GameStateBase", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref-to-GameStateBase in GameState.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GameState in GameState.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_GameStateBase", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GameState in GameState.o`

the errors do not seem to pertain to any specific area in the code, but prevent the game from compiling. I am completely clueless on these types of errors, and a google search yielded nothing.

Comment: In order not to have your question floating around as "unanswered" here, please write the solution as an answer yourself, wait a few days (I think the lock timer is two days) and accept it as the answer by clicking the "answered" symbol. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96395/set-my-own-question-as-solved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was missing an entire class of files: GameStateBase.h/m

Make sure you have all your source files, peeps!